# Purpose of the optional argument of \linebreak[]

Tags: line-breaking

What is the purpose of the optional argument of `\linebreak`? What is the difference between `\linebreak` and `\linebreak[1]`?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

test\linebreak test


test\linebreak[1] test

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think it's explained elsewhere on the site. Basically, `\linebreak` is the same as `\linebreak[4]` and means “break here, no discussion about it”; with `\linebreak[0]` you simply mark a possible break point, overriding TeX's default rules if necessary; `\linebreak[1]`, `\linebreak[2] and `\linebreak[3]` set “more desirable” break points.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the explanation! Makes perfect sense!